# Creating gentle random movement with UIButtons and CoreAnimation

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, core-animation, uitouch

I'm trying to create an animation on the iPhone with a collection of UIButtons, each of which should slowly and randomly move around inside a UIView, bouncing off one another. I realise that this is a very open-ended question, so I'm just looking for a better name for such an effect, so that I can do some searching. Pulsating seemed logical, but most searches pull up regular movement in/out as a result for that.

I'm thinking almost like an "under a microscope" view of cells, where they're individually all moving around of their own accord, and bouncing off when they hit one another, or the effect of putting a lot of marbles in a box. I'll eventually want to implement the user "flicking" them about, but that's to come later.

Any ideas for where to begin looking? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look into some 2D physics engines like [Chipmunk](http://chipmunk-physics.net/) or [Box2D](http://box2d.org/) since they will provide collision detection and *proper* reactions on their own. You can then model your `UIButtons` as simple rigid bodies with very low initial velocity. Animating the buttons is as simple as manually moving them on every draw tick.

Comment: Box2D looks promising but just about every tutorial I can find is either pre-ARC and throwing up hundreds of errors as soon as I report it, or is designed to work with cocos2d, which I'm not using. Any idea where I could find a little more help on it?

Comment: I can't be much of help on Box2D - I've personally only used Chipmunk and I highly encourage you to use it as well! The plain C version (not Obj-c one) is free and well documented, so it shouldn't be much of a struggle ;)

Comment: It seems like most of the tutorials I'm finding for Chipmunk are outdated, I'm getting a lot of errors from changes to structs etc. Seems pretty confusing. Are you aware of a recent (ARC, Chipmunk 6) tutorial I could follow to get the basics down? I'm no C programmer, really..

Answer (score 0):

I'd first google on Brownian Motion, which is presumably more random than cells under a microscope since cells could, at least in theory, have some purpose and direction.

But you might also want to look at flocking or swarming behavior, it isn't what you are asking about but it could be visually interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your buttons to move in a randomly chosen straight line until they bump into something, or do you want them to meander?

I don't know of any examples of what you're trying to do, but I could recommend some things to look into.

You could pre-generate a CGPath and then animate the buttons along the path using a CAKeyframeAnimation object.

Detecting collisions so that they bounce off of each other is tricky. You have to interrogate the view's layer's presentationLayer. You could either get the presentationLayer's frame of each button and check for intersection, or use the hitTest method  to check the corners of each frame to see if they fall inside the frame of another button.

I have a sample app on Github that illustrates animating a view along a curved path, and it also shows how to use the CALayer hitTest method to detect taps in an image view while it's animating.

You can get to the Github project by ***[clicking here](https://github.com/DuncanMC/iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo)***.

Comment: I want them to move randomly, they shouldn't go in straight lines, no, randomly changing direction wherever they please, etc.